# How to dynamically display MySQL data using jQuery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, dynamic

I have a PHP page that lists a bunch of words that it grabs from a MySQL database table. It displays the words in different sizes based on a count in the table:

```
<?php
 $selectStr = "select * from test";

 if ($results = MySQL($dbName, $selectStr))
 {
  $rowCount = MySQL_NUMROWS($results);
 }

 $i = 0;
 while ($i < $rowCount)
 {
  echo '<div style="float: left; font-size:' . (MySQL_RESULT($results,$i,'count') * 5) . 'px;">' . MySQL_RESULT($results,$i,'word') . '</div>';
  $i++;
 }
?>
```

The trick is that I want the content to display dynamically. So if a user is sitting on the page, and one of the word counts goes up, I want the word to change size without the user refreshing the page.

I am a novice with jQuery. I have used it a bit before, but only using examples. Can someone steer me in a good direction to have my page dynamically change the content without refreshing?

Comment: Sounds like you have to implement long polling. [This article is pretty decent](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) but there are others out there as well.

Comment: You could do this using AJAX or even better with [Node](http://nodejs.org)

Comment: Thanks...long polling and Node sound great, but I think they are a bit over my head at this point.

Comment: can someone please help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120124/insert-dynamic-select-box-value-in-mysql-database-and-show-data-submitted-messag/44123272#44123272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can auto refresh your page body like this ... give body id='body'

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var auto_refresh = setInterval(
         function ()
         {
          $('#body').load('wordscount.php').fadeIn("slow");
         }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id='content'></div>
 </body>
```

Dont forget to include jquery inside your head tag

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reloading the while body with AJAX; you should a div or something similar... <div id="content">

Comment: He can reload any html tag after sometime ... I just gave him an example to reload a portion of his page

Comment: OK. I can put it all in a div with id="content", and then I would just have to replace the #body above with #content? And where would I put all of this code? At the end of the <head>?

Comment: yes just replace #body with #content and put this script inside head tag and on load call your php script that will get the all the words from table

Comment: I'm still missing something. I have the script up top, with the php page in .load('getData.php'). Do I have anything in the content div? Is i just blank ( <div id="content"></div> )? How do I call my php script on load?

Answer (score 0):

It calls the file rowfunctie.php every 30000ms and fills the topbar diff with with the result of the getRows function.

```
<div id="center-rows">
  <div id="links">Nu&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="rows">
    <div id="topbar"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="rechts">&nbsp;aantal rijen</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doRequest() {
  jQuery("#topbar").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "rowfunctie.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        jQuery("#topbar").html(html);
        jQuery("#topbar").fadeIn('slow',function() {
        setTimeout('doRequest()',30000);
      });
   }
 });
 });
}
doRequest();
</script>
```

rowfunctie.php should look like this beneath:

```
<?php 
 $selectStr = "select * from test";

 if ($results = MySQL($dbName, $selectStr))
 {
  $rowCount = MySQL_NUMROWS($results);
 }

 $i = 0;
 while ($i < $rowCount)
 {
  echo '<div style="float: left; font-size:' . (MySQL_RESULT($results,$i,'count') * 5) . 'px;">' . MySQL_RESULT($results,$i,'word') . '</div>';
  $i++;
 }
?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand this at all. Is rowfuntie.php just the file that I wrote up top?

Comment: that's right! Only then you need to put that in a function called getRows(). Do you understand?

Comment: I don't, sorry I'm a novice with javascript and jQuery. What goes in the function getRows()?

Comment: Sorry you don't need to put this in an function. I edited my answer and put in the rowfunctie.php. I also edited something in the javascript function above. But this should work i just tested it.