# Insert Dynamic Select Box Value In Mysql Database And Show Data Submitted Message

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dynamic

In the below form i am loading question and answers from mysql database based on asset title value and submitting dynamic custom questions value to database. **( this is working fine )**
but my problem is i am not getting message when form value is submited to database for assets who have less than 15 custom questions.

I guess i am doing something wrong in my **createlead.php** file if condition...

Please help.

If you think this problem can be solved with another method then please let me know.

[image]
[image]
**Loading dynamic custom questions from mysql database based on asset title value**

```
<?php  
 //load_data.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
 $output = '';
 if(isset($_POST["assetid"]))  
 {  
  if($_POST["assetid"] != '')
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM cq WHERE assetid = '".$_POST["assetid"]."'";

  }  
  else
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM cq WHERE assetid = 'akash'";
       // i dont want to load any database so used wrong query

  }
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  $quesno = 1;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '<div class="col-sm-6">';
       $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
       $output .= '<label for="campaignname">'.$row["cqname"].'</label>';
       $output .= '<select name="cq'.$quesno.'" size="5" class="form-control" required>';
       // $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["product_name"].'</div>';
       // $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row["cqname"].'<br></td>';
       $output .= '<option value="" required>Select Custom Question Answer</option>
                   <option value="'.$row["cqa1"].'">'.$row["cqa1"].'</option>
                   <option value="'.$row["cqa2"].'">'.$row["cqa2"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa3"].'">'.$row["cqa3"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa4"].'">'.$row["cqa4"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa5"].'">'.$row["cqa5"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa6"].'">'.$row["cqa6"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa7"].'">'.$row["cqa7"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa8"].'">'.$row["cqa8"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa9"].'">'.$row["cqa9"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa10"].'">'.$row["cqa10"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa11"].'">'.$row["cqa11"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa12"].'">'.$row["cqa12"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa13"].'">'.$row["cqa13"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa14"].'">'.$row["cqa14"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa15"].'">'.$row["cqa15"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa16"].'">'.$row["cqa16"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa17"].'">'.$row["cqa17"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa18"].'">'.$row["cqa18"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa19"].'">'.$row["cqa19"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa20"].'">'.$row["cqa20"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa21"].'">'.$row["cqa21"].'</option>

                   </select>';
       // $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10"><hr></td></tr>';
       $output .= '</div></div></div>';
       $quesno++;
  }  
  echo $output;
 }  
 ?>
```

**Jquery ( Sending form fields value to php file) :-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // submit form
    $("#newleadform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

        $(".text-danger").remove();

        var form = $(this);

        // validation 
    var assettitle = $("#assettitle").val();
    var customquestion1 = $("#cq1").val();
    var customquestion2 = $("#cq2").val();
    var customquestion3 = $("#cq3").val();
    var customquestion4 = $("#cq4").val();
    var customquestion5 = $("#cq5").val();
    var customquestion6 = $("#cq6").val();
    var customquestion7 = $("#cq7").val();
    var customquestion8 = $("#cq8").val();
    var customquestion9 = $("#cq9").val();
    var customquestion10 = $("#cq10").val();
    var customquestion11 = $("#cq11").val();
    var customquestion12 = $("#cq12").val();
    var customquestion13 = $("#cq13").val();
    var customquestion14 = $("#cq14").val();
    var customquestion15 = $("#cq15").val();

        if(assettitle) {
            //submit the form to server
            $.ajax({
                url : '../pages/php_action/addnewlead/createlead.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(response) {

                    // remove the error 
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                    if(response.success == true) {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');

                        // reset the form
                        $("#newleadform")[0].reset();

                    } else {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');
                    }  // /else
                } // success  
            }); // ajax subit               
        } /// if


        return false;
    }); // /submit form for create member
}); // /add modal
```

**createlead.php ( submit form fields value to database) :-**

```
<?php 

require_once 'db_config.php';

//if form is submitted
if($_POST) {    
$validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

$assettitle= $_POST['assettitle'];
$customquestion1= $_POST['cq1'];
$customquestion2= $_POST['cq2'];
$customquestion3= $_POST['cq3'];
$customquestion4= $_POST['cq4'];
$customquestion5= $_POST['cq5'];
$customquestion6= $_POST['cq6'];
$customquestion7= $_POST['cq7'];
$customquestion8= $_POST['cq8'];
$customquestion9= $_POST['cq9'];
$customquestion10= $_POST['cq10'];
$customquestion11= $_POST['cq11'];
$customquestion12= $_POST['cq12'];
$customquestion13= $_POST['cq13'];
$customquestion14= $_POST['cq14'];
$customquestion15= $_POST['cq15'];





$sql = "INSERT INTO ltfs (assettitle, customquestion1, customquestion2, customquestion3, customquestion4, customquestion5, customquestion6, customquestion7, customquestion8, customquestion9, customquestion10, customquestion11, customquestion12, customquestion13, customquestion14, customquestion15) VALUES ('$assettitle', '$customquestion1', '$customquestion2', '$customquestion3', '$customquestion4', '$customquestion5', '$customquestion6', '$customquestion7', '$customquestion8', '$customquestion9', '$customquestion10', '$customquestion11', '$customquestion12', '$customquestion13', '$customquestion14', '$customquestion15')";


$query = $connect->query($sql);


if($query === TRUE) {
    $validator['success'] = true;
    $validator['messages'] = "Your lead successfully submited to quality team";     
} else {        
    $validator['success'] = false;
    $validator['messages'] = "Error while adding the lead information";
}

// close the database connection
$connect->close();

echo json_encode($validator);

}
```

Comment: *"for assets who have less than 15 custom questions"* - I don't see where you're checking for `<15` anywhere.

Comment: I am getting msg only if all 15 custom question value inserted into database... 

I guess i'm doing something wrong here.

if($query === TRUE) {
    $validator['success'] = true;
    $validator['messages'] = "Your lead successfully submited to quality team";     
} else {        
    $validator['success'] = false;
    $validator['messages'] = "Error while adding the lead information";
}

Answer (score 0):

I think doing mistake here

```
if($query === TRUE)
```

You can do as

```
if($query){//you message}else{//error message}
```

Comment: Thank You @ShahzaibChadhar. But this is not working brother.
This is working only for assets who have 15 questions. ( same like my code [ if($query === TRUE) ] )
And for assets who have less than 15 custom questions field value is inserting in the database but not showing message.